# Ansible task to to get the localhost ip address and replace in the destination file with value

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

i am running below task and replacing whole content in the destination file with ip address

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
    - copy: content="{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}" dest=/root/curator.yml
```

i have variable in curator.yml, i want to update variable {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }} with ip address.

```
---
client:
  hosts:
    - {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
  port: 9200
  url_prefix:
  use_ssl: False
  ssl_no_validate: False
  http_auth:
  timeout: 30
  master_only: False

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile:
  logformat: default
  blacklist: ['elasticsearch', 'urllib3']
```

When i execute above playbook task it's replacing whole information in curator.yml with ip address in the debug output

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
        "10.0.0.5"
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_default_ipv4.address": "10.0.0.5"
}

TASK [copy] *********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

i am also included below task but looks like it's not working

```
#- name: rewrite
#  vars:
#    ansible_default_ipv4.address: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address[0] }}"
#  template:
#    src: templates/curator.yml.j2
#    dest: /root/curator.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with your copy and template tasks:

1. Copy Task - As you are using `content` parameter, it will "set the contents of a file directly to the specified value" [copy_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/copy_module.html)
2. Template task - You can't define/update vars (or even set_fact) with .("dot") notation and you don't even need to, as the `ansible_default_ipv4.address` variable is already defined and the value is set.

This will work:

```
---
- name: Update ip
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - debug: var=ansible_default_ipv4.address
    - name: Template file with ip
      template:
        src: templates/curator.yml.j2
        dest: /root/curator.yml
...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me when i run task alone.
When i included with other task it complaining.

The error appears to have been in '/jenkins/var/lib/tasks/main.yml': line 15, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Update ip
  ^ here